# Charge conservation in photoelctric effect

Tags: electrostatics

Electrostatics-

I'll quote from my book:

> Photoelectric Effect : When light of sufficiently high frequency is incident on a metal surface then some electrons gain energy from light and come out of the metal surface and remaining metal becomes charged.

And-

> Charge conservation is always valid.

Then, where do the electrons coming out of the metal (during photoelectric effect) go? And how does charge conservation remain true there?

Silly question, but please, explain. 
Thank-you!

Comment: In a vacuum, they would simply fly to the infinity. In real world, they would hit something else in the environment. The total charge is conserved; the metal gains plus charge as the electron is transported away (wherever it goes) carrying a minus charge. The situation is analogous to space craft leaving the earth when they are propelled fast enough.

Comment: @Echows , Ok! Got it! Thanks! You could post it as an answer so I may accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the metal plate was completely electrically isolated then as the photoelectrons left the surface the metal would become positively charged.
As more electrons left the metal plate and the charge built up some of the electrons would be attracted back to the metal surface.
Eventually the positive charge on the metal plate would be large enough to attract back all the photoelectrons.
If at the end of the demonstration the positively charged plate was connect to the earth then electrons would move from the earth to neutralise the metal plate.

--

Here is a schematic diagram of an apparatus used to show the photoelectric effect.

[image].

As you can see the photoelectrons traverse a gap in the circuit which is not normally conducting.
So there is a complete "conducting" circuit.